# Using the cells function inside a formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Let's say we have this piece of code as an example

```
Worksheets"Sheets1".Cells(1,4).Formula= "=SUM(Cells(x1,y1):Cells(x2:y2))"
```

Is there anyway to make this work ?
The idea is that if I were to put this piece of code in a sub-routine, I could make the range of the sum dependent on the results of the subroutine.
Example, If I were to write a subroutine that counts how many cells have numbers on them (for example 20), I could then use that as range.
So something like this

```
count = 20    
Worksheets"Sheets1".Cells(1,4).Formula= "=SUM(Cells(1,1):Cells(count:1)"
```

I would want this to be equivalent to writing =SUM(A1:A20)

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
Worksheets("Sheets1").Cells(1,4).Formula= _
        "=SUM(" & Cells(1, 1).Resize(count, 1).address & ")"
```

Comment: Yeap this seems to work like a charm!
one question though, why do you need to use the address ?

Comment: @NunoSantos because you're building an Excel formula? If you want to evaluate the result of `WorksheetFunction.Sum` over a `Range` object, then you don't need the address, because the function can work with a `Range` object. But here you're piecing together a string representing an Excel formula, not evaluating a function.

Comment: Whatever you pass to `Formula` has to be a string which would be a valid worksheet function; as if you had entered it in the formula bar.  You can't mix VBA syntax and formula syntax and expect the cell to be able to evaluate that.

Comment: Also just pointing out that if you want to toggle absolute referencing i.e. the difference between "$A$1" and "A1" using `Address`, you can use true/false parameters after: `Cells(1,1).Address(false,false)` = "A1" `Cells(1,1).Address(true,true)` = "$A$1" - very handy to know if you ever fill a range!